# AWS S3 integration with Google app acript

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-apps-script

I was trying to use the putObject() function of AWS S3 to put a object into a folder in a bucket, I am not able to specify the folder name in the function, I was able to put the object into the bucket but not into the folder. Is there any way in which I can specify the Folder name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no separate folder names.

The object key is path + filename, so to upload `cat.jpg` into `images/funny/` you upload the file as `images/funny/cat.jpg`.

Do not use a leading `/`.